# What's wrong with my Hello World AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is the code, not sure why it's not working. Got the `angular.min.js` file in the same folder as `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should put the angular.min.js script at the top of the page actually, not that putting the script at the bottom of the body is bad, but the upfront cost of loading it, is offset for the rest of the app

Comment: I am not sure you should have the controller function inside the tag with the ng-app attribute. The way I've always done it is to always put my controllers in a separate .js file, and using a <script>  tag referencing it in the <head>  of my HTML document.

Comment: Thanks for input. Tried both, but none worked

Comment: mine isn't to fix your problem, just a comment on the code

Comment: Oh, thanks man. That's what I thought as well; This tutorial is pretty outdated, which explains the old way of declaring controllers and other practices

Comment: @roadtocode do you actually have a link to the tutorial? for angular, don't use anything that hasn't been updated (or be really careful) in at least 2014, because they made a big change in 2014, and actually are on the way to upgrade it by next year with a new huge (2.0) release

Answer (score 1):

It's the old syntax to declare controller. Now you can't declare angualar controller as global function and you should use `angular.module("appName",[]).controller("CtrlName",function(){});` instead.

Rewrite your script to:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
  $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
}
```

And change your html file second line to

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: I would put it inside the <head>  tag of the HTML document.

Comment: Same place as your script which after `<script src="angular.min.js"></script>`. You can rewrite your script like this `var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
  $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
}` and change your html file line 2 to `<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">`

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a whole framework and not just a simple call like that. You'll need actually do something like (in a js file usually):

```
angular.module("myapp",[]).controller('HelloWorldCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.helloMessage = "hello World";
}]);
```

and the HTML for it is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("myapp",[]).controller('HelloWorldCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.helloMessage = "hello World";
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(note this isn't best practices, but to help you get started, reference here for best practice, that i find accurate: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module("HelloWorldApp", [])
        .controller("HelloWorldController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.helloWorld = "Hello World";
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="HelloWorldApp" ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
    <h1>{{helloWorld || "undefined"}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```